# HDD hangs all programs that try to access it

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, freeze, unresponsive

I have a SATA HDD which freezes every process that tries to access the drive (fdisk, disks, gparted, parted, fsck, e2fsck, everything) except **lsblk** which shows that the device is present:

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
[...] 
sdf           8:80   0   3,7T  0 disk
```

I suspect the partition table or some blocks are corrupt but I can neither verify that by using fsck nor correct it because every process trying to access the drive becomes unresponsive.

The output of **dmesg** when the drive is connected where the lines marked with **<-- x** are printed in red:

```
[ 7078.631056] usb 6-4: new SuperSpeed USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
[ 7078.651835] usb 6-4: New USB device found, idVendor=067b, idProduct=2773, bcdDevice= 1.00
[ 7078.651839] usb 6-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 7078.651842] usb 6-4: Product: USB3.0 DUAL DOCK 
[ 7078.651843] usb 6-4: Manufacturer: Prolific
[ 7078.651844] usb 6-4: SerialNumber: PROLIFICM000000003
[ 7078.652673] usb-storage 6-4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 7078.652849] scsi host9: usb-storage 6-4:1.0
[ 7079.688634] scsi 9:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WDC WD40 EZRX-11SPEB0     80.0 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
[ 7079.689121] sd 9:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg6 type 0
[ 7079.689424] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdf] Very big device. Trying to use READ CAPACITY(16).
[ 7079.689781] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdf] 7813971633 512-byte logical blocks: (4.00 TB/3.64 TiB)
[ 7079.690108] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdf] Write Protect is off
[ 7079.690112] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdf] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
[ 7079.690437] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdf] No Caching mode page found <-- x
[ 7079.690443] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdf] Assuming drive cache: write through <-- x
[ 7079.719414] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdf] Very big device. Trying to use READ CAPACITY(16).
[ 7110.475497] usb 6-4: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
```

Now every process just freezes / hangs without any information whatsoever. For example, I started **parted** which works fine but as soon as the drive gets connected it hangs until I disconnect the drive.

When disconnecting the drive **dmesg** shows the following:

```
[ 7228.828276] usb 6-4: USB disconnect, device number 13
[ 7228.828416] sd 9:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
[ 7228.848224] print_req_error: 73 callbacks suppressed
[ 7228.848228] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdf, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 7228.848235] buffer_io_error: 86 callbacks suppressed
[ 7228.848236] Buffer I/O error on dev sdf, logical block 0, async page read
[ 7228.848243] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdf, sector 1 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 7 prio class 0
[ 7228.848246] Buffer I/O error on dev sdf, logical block 1, async page read
[ 7228.848247] Buffer I/O error on dev sdf, logical block 2, async page read
[ 7228.848249] Buffer I/O error on dev sdf, logical block 3, async page read
[ 7228.848250] Buffer I/O error on dev sdf, logical block 4, async page read
[ 7228.848251] Buffer I/O error on dev sdf, logical block 5, async page read
[ 7228.848253] Buffer I/O error on dev sdf, logical block 6, async page read
[ 7228.848255] Buffer I/O error on dev sdf, logical block 7, async page read
[ 7228.848305] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdf, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 8 prio class 0
[ 7228.848311] Buffer I/O error on dev sdf, logical block 0, async page read
[ 7228.848314] Buffer I/O error on dev sdf, logical block 1, async page read
[ 7228.848338] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdf, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 8 prio class 0
[ 7228.848345] ldm_validate_partition_table(): Disk read failed.
[ 7228.848351] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdf, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 7228.848357] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdf, sector 1 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 7228.848362] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdf, sector 2 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 7228.848366] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdf, sector 3 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 7228.848371] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdf, sector 4 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 7228.848377] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdf, sector 5 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 7228.848455] Dev sdf: unable to read RDB block 0
[ 7228.848576]  sdf: unable to read partition table
[ 7228.876530] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdf] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 7228.876534] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdf] Sense not available.
[ 7228.876537] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdf] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
[ 7228.876542] sdf: detected capacity change from 7813971633 to 0
[ 7228.876545] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdf] Attached SCSI disk
```

I found posts that describe similar behaviour but the solutions such as rewriting the partition table do not work for me as no process regarding the drive is responsive.

Maybe the system tries to access the drive to mount it and gets stuck so every other process waits for it or something like that it feels like..

Comment: What spec PC is this happening on? The errors say that the system can't handle 4TB SATA drives. Lots of PC's in the past had maximum SATA capacity of 2TB

Comment: @JohnnyVegas I use a very modern system with an x570 board and 3rd gen Ryzen CPU so I don't think this could be the problem eventhough the error message suggests it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I connected the drive to a Windows 10 machine and it showed me some indications that this drive was originally used in a "WD MyBook" so I found a tool called "WD Unlocker" with which this drive was locked. I used this tool to erase the drive and after that it behaved like a normal drive which I was able to format as ext4 and Linux use.

I still do not know how this tool managed it to completely prevent any investigation from Linux by freezing every process but I guess the original problem is now resolved.